# Cant read lines text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, python-3.6, raspberry-pi3

i have been using python to read and write text files, with variables separated by lines. I was trying to find how many lines are in a particular file and read what's on a certain line, however it seems the number of lines is 0, even though when i print the file it gives me the correct output. My code is below:

```
import random
HUBCop = open("HUBCOUNT.txt","r+")
HUBCount = int(HUBCop.read())
HUBCop.close()
HUBNUM = str(input("Hub number: "))

if (HUBNUM == "new"):
    newHubOp=open("Hub " + (HUBCount + 1) +".txt", "w+")
    HUBNUM = str(HUBCount+1)
    HUBCop = open("HUBCOUNT.txt","w+")
    HUBCop.write(str(HUBCount + 1))
    output1 = input("Output 1: ")
    output2 = input("Output 2: ")
    newHubOp.write(output1 + "\n" + output2 + "1")
    newHubOp.close()
    TimesRun = 1
else:
    HubOp = open("Hub " + HUBNUM + ".txt","r+")
    HubOp.seek(0)
    HubLines = HubOp.readlines()
    HubOp.seek(0)
    print(str(len(HubLines)))
    print (HubLines[1])
```

the file Hub 1.txt contains this:

```
true
false
1
```

however, when I run the code it gives me this output:

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/NN.py", line 23, in <module>
print (HubLines[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

take note I am new to python and I am using a raspberry pi 3 with python 3.6

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: This works fine for me

Comment: Works fine for me too. Did you post the complete code?Error is shown in line 23. Please post the complete code so that error can be traced

Comment: the complete code is long...ive edited it though

Comment: What's in `HUBCOUNT.txt`?

Comment: This won't work `open("Hub " + (HUBCount + 1) +".txt", "w+")` because `(HUBCount + 1)` isn't a string.

Comment: HUBCOUNT.txt: `1`

Comment: oh! good point PM 2Ring, saved me a lot of trouble there!

Comment: @3NiGMa I don't think so. `HUBCOUNT` is an `int`, and `int` doesn't have a `.txt` method.

Comment: Also, `HUBCount = int(HUBCop.read())` reads the entire `HUBCop` file into a string, then tries to convert that whole string to a single integer. That's probably _not_ what you want. ;)

Comment: Whats the desired output???

Comment: Sometimes printing relevant data can be an effective troubleshooting tool. What happens if you print `HubLines`  right after the line `HubLines = HubOp.readlines()`? From your Traceback, it looks like `HubLines` is empty,

Comment: @PM 2Ring its worked fine for me so far, if its not broken, don't fix it!

Comment: See https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/2q97YCXcLOlkoR2jKKEMQ-wkG9k=/0x0:900x500/1200x800/filters:focal%28378x178:522x322%29/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49493993/this-is-fine.0.jpg :)

Comment: I can guarantee that if your file contains `true` `false` `1` on separate lines then `int(HUBCop.read())` will **not** work. It will raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'true\nfalse\n1\n'`

Comment: :D not sure exactly what message you were trying to convey with that image PM 2Ring, but i am simply going to wait until it actually creates a problem to fix it, also @wwii, hublines is not empty, although python does seem to think it has 0 lines???

Comment: OTOH, if `HUBCop` only contains a single line, and that line has a single number, then `int(HUBCop.read())` is correct.

Comment: @PM 2Ring it does, Hub 1.txt contains those three lines, however HUBCOUNT.txt holds one single number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.readlines() returns a list of lines
So the line that you read should be in:

```
HubLines[0]
```

or try just:

```
HubLines
```

When you try to access **HubLines[1]** it says **out of range** because it doesn't exist

Comment: so what would be an alternative method to read the second line of the file? also why is the length of HubLines 0?